# JQuery UI autocomplete with Ajax PHP MYSQL not displaying result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have implemented `JQuery Ui autocomplete` function to display content from the `database` using the below code

**Script**

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#query" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'search.php'
});
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 " >
  <input style="width:100%;"class="form-control"  id="query" placeholder="Search" type="text">       
</div>
```

When I run the above I get the following result within `span notification`

```
<span role="status" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
<div style="display: none;">
 3 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</div>
<div style="display: none;">
4 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</div>
<div>4 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</div></span>
```

But the autocomplete `UL>li` filed does not hold any value

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; top: 902.452px; left: 72.7257px; width: 372px;">
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-divider"></li>
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-divider"></li>
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-divider"></li>
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-divider"></li>
</ul>
```

This is what I'm able to see

[image]

And here is the result that I'm getting in `chrome ->Network`

```
[{name: "asa"}, {name: "Abhijit Das"}, {name: "Abhijit Das"}, {name: "Abhijit Das"}]
```

Comment: What is the response of the AJAX call? You can see it in Chrome F12 -> Network

Comment: does your `search.php` returns an array of objects?

Comment: @marmeladze it returns json as the above which I have posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @marmeladze suggested, your problem is most likely the response format of the php code. According to https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ you should have a simple array like this:

```
[
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++"
];
```

According to http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ Multiple types are supported:

> Array: An array can be used for local data.
>   There are two supported formats:
>   An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
>   An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
>   The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will
>   be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If
>   just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you
>   provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the
>   label.

Another example with remote server (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote):

```
[
  {"id":"Nycticorax nycticorax",
   "label":"Black-crowned Night Heron",
   "value":"Black-crowned Night Heron"},
  {"id":"Corvus cornix",
   "label":"Hooded Crow",
   "value":"Hooded Crow"}
]
```